# Implementing a "Custom Comparison Date Range" in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, date-range, date-comparison

I am encountering a challenge in implementing a custom comparison date range feature in Looker Studio. My goal is to enable users to select two different date ranges: one for the primary analysis and another for comparison.

Here are the details of the issue:

1. Date Range Controls: Currently, I have two date range controls on my report. One should determine the main period for analysis, while the other should define the comparison period.
2. Platform Limitation: Looker Studio seems not to offer a straightforward solution for linking the second date range for dynamic comparison in the report. The standard date range controls do not appear to support this functionality natively.
3. Required Solution: I am looking for a way to allow users to choose a custom comparison period through a second date range control, which can be used to dynamically and interactively compare data from the main period.

Any suggestions, workarounds, or advice on how to effectively implement this feature in Looker Studio would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the comparison date range, i suggest to use normal filter instead of "Date range control" that should be work around in your case.

Let me know if that works.